# Font-size not same in firefox and safari

Tags: css

I have using font size 14px in body and according to this i have give size to all element in percentage .But the problem is firefox is fine but in safari and chrome the size is not same .Any one help me please

I know css hack but i need a proper way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the base font size for the body, for example:

```
body {
    font-size: 63%;
}
```

Then, for the font sizes for the rest of the elements, use relative units such as `em`. For example:

```
#navigation {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: It created same issue.safari and chrome showing different size:(

Comment: Kindly post your implementation (css sections) that cause the issue